# How can i update database by updating data in DataGridView by a button click?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, sql-update

**I have bounded sql database table with vb form DataGridView through Visual studio wizard.**
I tried below code and it executes successfully and show message "Updated Successfully" but in reality it does not makes any changes to SQL Database. When i reload the form i am not seeing any changes. I am new to VB.Net and only this thing is resisting me to complete my project. Please help...Thanks in advance

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class FormUpdate

'Variables declared here
Dim Con As New SqlConnection
Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim cmdString As String
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
Dim cmdbl As New SqlCommandBuilder

Public Sub FormUpdate_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ShipmentDataSetDataGridView.Shipment_Main' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Shipment_MainTableAdapter2.Fill(Me.ShipmentDataSetDataGridView.Shipment_Main)

 'CONNECTION STRING FOR THE DATABASE
    Con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=TARIQUE;Initial Catalog=shipment;Integrated Security=True"
End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

Try
   Con.Open()
   cmdbl = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
   da.Update(dt)
   MessageBox.Show("Updated successfully!")
Catch ex As Exception
       MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)

End Try
   Con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Please put up the code that you are using to initialize your objects `da`, `dt`, and `Con`.

Comment: @S.AdamNissley   Code added....

Comment: Did you mean this code...here is this one i am using to fill data grid view on search....  `'To perform search operation by search button
    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click  
        dt.Clear()  
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt  
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing  

        If txtSearch.Text = Nothing Then  
            cmdString = "SELECT * FROM Shipment_Main"  
            da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmdString, Con)
            da.Fill(dt)  
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `UpdateCommand` to your `SqlDataAdapter`. You can do this manually in code, or you can configure a DataSet using the GUI in Visual Studio.

It looks like you could benefit from reading the documentation. I would recommned starting here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254931(v=vs.110).aspx
There are 9 subtopics in that article, and you should fully read at least ***Retrieving Data Using a DataReader*** and ***Updating Data Sources with DataAdapters***.

Comment: Thanks to all now my update button is working properly.....I was forget to set Primary key on database....